# stripslashes issue in php

Tags: php

when i use stripslashes in php  but i did not get the exact solution. I have menstion below which i used in my code those are
Example if i have the value in table like `suresh\'s kuma\"r`
i trying to display the value in the following three formats but no one is giving exact value

```
1) value=<?=stripslashes($row[1])?> //output is suresh's
2) value='<?=stripslashes($row[1])?>' //output is suresh
3) value="<?=stripslashes($row[1])?>" //output is suresh's kuma
```

But the exact output i need is `suresh's kuma"r`

let me know how to resolve the this issue?

Comment: You forgot to describe the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing do to with stripslashes. If I guess correctly, the problem lies in the fact that in your examples quotes **break the html** field attribute;

I'll show you by manually echoing out your $row content as per your infos:

1. value=sures kumar   --> leads to browser to interpret this as `value="sures" kumar`
2. value='suresh'khumar --> well, same story `value='sures' khumar`
3. value="Suresh"Khumar -->what can I say...you know the drill

Escaping the quotes won't affect html, since backslashes has no meaning in html. 
Both `value="Suresh"` and `value="Suresh\"` will work fine for the browser, but your name will always be interpreted by the browser as some unknown attribute, leaving only the first part inside the value.

What you might do, instead, is apply `htmlentities($row[1],ENT_QUOTES)` so that they get converted in the equivalent entity (`&quote;`,for ex.) and **not** break your value attribute. See [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Another issue is that you **shouldn't be having backslashes** in your database in the first place; this might be due to the presence of `magic_quotes` enabled in your provider, or you passing manually `addslashes()` or other wrong trickery. If you want to insert into a database values containing quotes, use the escaping mechanism provided by your database driver (mysql_real_escape_string() in mysql, for ex.), or better tools (preparated statements with query bindings).

You should first get rid of all the slashes using that stripslashes and re-saving back the content; but slashes or not, the issue would appear again if you don't format that appropriately for your html, as I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want stripslashes instead of [addslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)? Is the purpose is to quote the " characters?

Comment: @Suresh what's the use of addslashes? if for the database, it's wrong. If for html, it's useless...

Comment: @DamienPirsy that's fair enough. If you are *sure* that you want only to quote ' and ", then use it. If not, use htmlentities().